# Why doesn't stdbuf line buffer the output of some simple c programs

Tags: c, bash, shell, io, buffering

I'm trying to use stdbuf to line buffer the output of a program but I can't seem to make it work as I would expect. Using this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main (void)
{
    int i=0;
    for(i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        printf("This is part one");
        fflush(stdout);
        sleep(1);
        printf(" and this is part two\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I see `This is part one`, a one second wait then `and this is part two\nThis is part one`.

I expected that running it as

```
stdbuf --output=L ./test.out
```

would cause the output to be a 1 second delay and then `This is part one and this is part two\n` repeating at one second intervals. Instead I see the same output as in the case when I don't use stdbuf.

Am I using stdbuf incorrectly or does the call to fflush count as "adjusting" the buffering as described in the [sdtbuf man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/stdbuf)?

If I can't use stdbuf to line buffer in this way is there another command line tool that makes it possible?

Comment: But you are already explicitly flushing stdout, after the first `printf` which means it will be sent to terminal immediately.

Comment: Yes, but I thought that the point of stdbuf was to allow modification of the buffering of the command output.

Comment: It probably did modify the buffering ... but then your program flushes the buffers, which is orthogonal to whatever `stdbuf` does.

Comment: My mental picture of how stdbuf would work was that it forks the command and pipes stdout (in this case) back to stdbuf which buffers output until a \n is received. I thought that means it could suppress the fflush.

Comment: Nope. If that were the case, then the program adjusting buffering won't make any difference. There's a reason why it only works in specific circumstances (ELF programs using ISO C `FILE` streams): my guess is that it uses LD_PRELOAD or similar to load the standard library itself with some pre-set options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a couple of options that work for me, given the sample code, and run interactively (the output was to a pseudo-TTY):

```
./program | grep ^
./program | while IFS= read -r line; do printf "%s\n" "$line"; done
```

In a couple of quick tests, both output a complete line at a time. If you need to do pipe it further, `grep`'s `--line-buffered` option should be useful.

Comment: The first example solved my test problem. To make it work if the output is on stderr I needed to use process substitution like this ./program 2> >(grep ^ 1>&2)